# Connection Error with wget in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, download, wget

This is what my script looks like :

```
#!/bin/bash

WGETREF='https://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/technical/reference/GRCh38_reference_genome/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.fa'

wget $WGETREF
chmod +x get-ref.sh
```

I call it like so :

```
sbatch -A OD-projectID get-ref.sh
```

I tried doing a script because I will have to download lots of similar files that are 30+ Gb.
When doing `wget` directly in the command line, it starts the download as it should. However with the shell script, the output file gives me the following error :

```
Connecting to ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk (ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk)|193.62.193.140|:443... failed: Connection refused.
```

Is there something I should add to my script ?

I tried different ways of writing the `wget`  for instance calling for a 2nd script as so :

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -i url-ref.txt
```

with `url-ref.txt` being a simple text file with just the url.

Bash version : GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu).

This is what the debug output says :

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.20.3 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/foa003/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
asking libproxy about url 'https://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/technical/reference/GRCh38_reference_genome/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.fa'
libproxy suggest to use 'direct://'
Converted file name 'GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.fa' (UTF-8) -> 'GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.fa' (UTF-8)
--2023-05-18 11:36:52--  https://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/technical/reference/GRCh38_reference_genome/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.fa
Resolving ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk (ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk)... 193.62.193.140
Caching ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk => 193.62.193.140
Connecting to ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk (ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk)|193.62.193.140|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection refused.
Releasing 0x00005555558eb020 (new refcount 1).
```

I tried adding `ping google.com` before `wget` and it seems to work

Comment: Is it working and failing on the same computer, or different ones?

Comment: it's on the same computer

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. try adding bash version, how do you invloke the script and any other detail. BTW, always double quote variables `wget "$WGETREF"`

Comment: `wget --debug ...` might help.

Comment: Considering that the host name starts with `ftp.<something>` - maybe you want to use the FTP protocol to connect to it?

Comment: You could have a routing problem. Have you tried `traceroute 193.62.193.140` to see if the packets are dropped at some point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ping google.com` before `wget` helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).